# VS2008 build multiple configurations of the same project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dependencies, projects-and-solutions

I have three solutions which build two clients and a server, and share many libraries.  I would like to be able to combine these into a "master" solution that builds all the necessary projects.

For various reasons, which perhaps deserve a question of their own, some of the shared libraries are linked statically (.lib only) to one application and dynamically (.lib + .dll) to another application.  So a build would actually require building two separate configurations of a single project.  It looks like the VS dependencies don't handle this case, but I thought I would see if anyone else has already solved this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I'm using 4 solution configurations instead of two, e.g.,

```
Debug Clients
Release Clients
Debug Server
Release Server
```

And each solution configuration builds the appropriate project configs.  Then I can build everything by doing a "batch build" on whichever two I'm currently interested in, and apparently VS refuses to do parallel builds when using batch builds.